# Intuitive Numerical Analysis Texts

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Steven Strogatz has a great informal textbook on Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos. I have found it to be incredibly helpful to get an intuitive sense of what is going on and has been a great supplement with my much more formal text from Perko.

Anyways I was wondering if anyone knew of any similar informal, intuitive textbooks covering Numerical Analysis? I currently study out of Atkinson's Intro to Numerical Analysis. I am looking for a more informal numerical text aimed for upper level undergrads and first/second year grad students. I am currently a first year grad student studying for my qualifying exams. Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try these books:

- *Introduction to Applied Numerical Analysis* by [Richard Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hamming)
- *Numerical Methods That Work* by [Forman Acton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forman_S._Acton)

Answer (score 0):

For linear algebra, I like Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau.

Comment: Trefethen's book on spectral methods is also great.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little dense sometimes, but *Numerical Analysis* by Burden and Faires is a classic book on the subject.

Comment: I bought that in November actually. It has been helpful as a second resource